# AFIncrementalStore Duplicates Objects Edited by Multiple Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I am attempting to use AFIncrementalStore to share data managed by core data across multiple devices. For a simple example, I'm using this sample ToDo app https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-ios-core-data-buildpack-app and a server set up with the core data build pack.

When managed objects are created or modified they are properly added to the server database; however, when the same object is modified on a second device, the object is duplicated instead of updated. The same problem occurs if the app is deleted and reinstalled and then the previously created objects are modified.

How can this issue be corrected so the same set of managed objects can be manipulated by more than one device?

Comment: After briefly looking at the sample code and at AFIncrimentalStore, I didn't see any code that takes care of uniqing of the objects or find-or-create pattern. I guess you have to implement. Or am I missing something obvious here?